# Google Bar Graph Chart using php and mysql display will multi colors automatically?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-developers-console, google-developer-tools

I need Multi color Like Pie Chart, how to do that in Bar Graph Chart?

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "handsmec_sales", "handsmec_sales", "handsmec_sales_portal");  
$query2 = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%m/%Y') as date, SUM(order_total_after_tax) as number FROM tbl_order where status='Confirmed' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%Y/%m')";  
$result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $query2); 
?>

<div id="Salesman" style="width: 650px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add **{ role: 'style' }** to your data table. For all the columns that you want to have the same color, just specify an empty style ''. Then, on the column you want to be red, you could just specify **'red'** or **'#ff0000'** or 'color: red', etc. here the is reference [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Colors)

```
// example from Google
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
    ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333'],            // RGB value
    ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],            // English color name
    ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
    ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ], // CSS-style declaration
]);
```

Comment: var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
                          ['Username', 'Total Sales'],  
                          <?php  
                          while($sub_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))  
                          {  
                               echo "['".$sub_row["date"]."', ".$sub_row["number"]."],";  
                          }  
                          ?>  
                     ]);

Comment: var options = {
                     
          title : 'Month & Yearly Total Sales Values',
          'width':450,
                     'height':500,
          vAxis: {title: 'Total Sales'},
          hAxis: {title: 'Month & Year'},
          seriesType: 'bars',
          series: {5: {type: 'line'}}
          
        };
                var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('Salesman'));  
                chart.draw(data, options);  
           }

Comment: how to give color at PHP